# dota 2 - how do you see emoticons collection

Tags: dota-2

Basically... what title says.

I got an emoticons pack. Opened it so now I should have them. The thing is... where do I see them?

Comment: Yes. Only that... I checked inventory. Are not there.

Comment: Also, going to say that there's currently a bug with the new emote pack (winter battle pass reward 2) where they don't work in-game. They are probably fixing it but for the time they don't show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emoticon packs are consumable item in dota 2. They are not shown in armoury like other wearable items. When you open a emoticon pack in dota you are basically consuming it for your account.

To send a emoticon just click one when you are chatting in game using **return** key.

Answer (score 2):

Redeeming an emoticon pack in Dota 2 allows you to use their respective emoticons in any chat channels. The emoticons that you are able to use depend on which pack you activated.

They don't seem to appear in the inventory, most likely because they may not be intended to be traded.

A full list of emoticons and their associated emoticon packs can be found on the [Dota 2 wiki](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Emoticons). Try typing one of the emoticons from that pack you activated and see if it works.